# bootstrap carousel issue with height and controls

Tags: css, carousel

I am facing a issue with my bootstrap carousel as its going long as much the image is long, as well the carousel controls its coming up of the carousel where its appear ugly. I have make a screen record which will make easier to understand exactly how the issue is look like.

I wish if you can watch it were it will explain more of what I am looking for 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_9C8elqAscg

```
.carousel{margin-top: 20px;}.carousel .item img{margin: 0 auto; /* Align slide image horizontally center */}.bs-example{margin: 20px;}

<div class="bs-example">
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" role="listbox">
    <!-- Carousel indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="4"></li>
    </ol>   
    <!-- Wrapper for carousel items -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" class="myrdbtns">
        <div class="item active">
            <asp:Image ID="image" runat="server" alt="First Slide" ImageUrl='<%# "/images/AdsImgs/" + Eval("Img1") %>'></asp:Image>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <asp:Image ID="imgslide2" runat="server" alt="Second Slide" ImageUrl='<%# "/images/AdsImgs/" + Eval("Img2") %>'></asp:Image>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <asp:Image ID="imgslide3" runat="server" alt="Third Slide" ImageUrl='<%# "/images/AdsImgs/" + Eval("Img3") %>'></asp:Image>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <asp:Image ID="imgslide4" runat="server" alt="fourth Slide" ImageUrl='<%# "/images/AdsImgs/" + Eval("Img4") %>'></asp:Image>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <asp:Image ID="imgslide5" runat="server" alt="fifth Slide" ImageUrl='<%# "/images/AdsImgs/" + Eval("Img5") %>'></asp:Image>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Carousel controls -->
    <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev" >
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there are a couple of different ways you can go about making the image fit in the carousel.  First you can set the carousel item to have a specified height.  And then set the image to have a height and width of 100%.  There is a problem with this is that the images can become skewed and from your video I see that the one image is much taller than the others so this image may look kind of silly if you go this route.  Here is an example of how you can set the image height.

```
#myCarousel .item{
  height: 300px;
}
#myCarousel .item img{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Or you can set each of the items to have a background image and then set the background image to cover.  This may cut off some of the very tall image but at least the image will appear non pixelated.  Here is an example of that.

```
#myCarousel .item{
  height: 300px;
  background-position: center !Important;
  background-size: cover !Important;
}
```

Then for each item your html will look like so:

```
<div class="item" style="background: url('http://placehold.it/1080x720');">
     //your item content here
</div>
```

As for the carousel controls they are positioned absolutely in the carousel so you can control them by setting the left, right, top, and bottom of each control like so:

```
.carousel-control{
  top: 40px;
  bottom: 20px;
}
.carousel-control.left{
  left: 20px;
}
.carousel-control.right{
  right: 20px;
}
```

I have set up a demo of something that I think you are looking for here [JSFiddle Bootstrap Carousel](https://jsfiddle.net/wamosjk/qL3kwme6/)

In this demo I set the .item to have a padding-bottom of a percentage.  This will make the carousel responsive but you can set the .item to have a height as well.  Then I gave the `<p>` tag in each item to have a specified height and line height and set the carousel controls to appear underneath that.  If you have trouble with the text being too long you can either set this `<p>` tag to have a taller height or use text-overflow: elipsis or something to that nature.  Anyway it may not be exactly what you are looking for but it will at least get you started in the right direction.

Hope it helps.